# Adding entry to android manifest for Intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent, manifest

I am just building a very simple application. Three buttons. The first opens a browser, the second opens the phone and the third opens the Maps application. The purpose is to learn more about intents triggering the start up of other applications.

```
public void openBrowser(){
    //Create intent
    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.facebook.com"));
    startActivity(i);
}

public void openPhone(){
    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse("tel: +3531234567890"));
    startActivity(i);
}

public void openMap(){
    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:53.2803, -6.1529"));
    startActivity(i);

}
```

Should there be an entry in the manifest file for these particular intents?  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't need ManifestEntrys for built-in Intents.

What you may need are permissions:
An Activity (especially if it is not your own) may require you to have permissions to call this functionallity. A Barcode-scan App (i.e. BarcodeScanner from the XZing Team) which you can call via an Intent for the resultString inside a Barcode may require, that the caller has the Permission `CAMERA`. If you want to pick a Contact from the default Android Contact App, it will require you to have the `READ_CONTACTS` Permission. Otherwise it could be considered as kind of local exploit, if an App with no Permission is able to read Contacts via the Contacts-App - which of course - has this permission.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful answer. I will bear this in mind for future projects

Answer (score 0):

No, you only need to add entries for the Activities in your manifest file.

Comment: Ahh ok, I actually had a feeling that was the case. Do you have any idea why my application force closes when I press the buttons? Do I need to give it internet permission or anything like that in the case of the browser button?

Comment: Yeah, you need explicitly grant any permissions the application may need.

Comment: I solved my problem. I was not passing a view object to the methods and at runtime this was throwing an exception. the method declaration should be public function openBrowser(View v){}, openPhone(View v){} and openMap(View v){}.